# Property 'MediaScannerPlugin' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'

Tags: cordova-plugins, android-mediascanner

l am trying to use [Media Scanner Plugin](https://github.com/begrossi/MediaScannerPlugin#readme) . That Plugin is using to refreshing files folder  after downloading  . The problem is while i use this code below

```
    cordova.plugins.MediaScannerPlugin.scanFile(this.place + image);
 //This is the code line that you need.You need to use this line where your download thing  happens
```

i have error under `MediaScannerPlugin`

```
Property 'MediaScannerPlugin' does not exist on type 'CordovaPlugins'
```

Any idea please how to use this plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to add the plugin (using npmjs) before you can use it.

1) By using npmjs, change current directory to root cordova project.

2) Then you add the plugin to your project,

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mediascanner
```

3) To see if the plugin been installed succesfully in your project, you can type:

```
 cordova plugin
```

You can also verify package.json file (on base project directory),  by checking the plugin on dependencies and cordova plugins specification.

4) When the plugin has js file for initialization or any certain function, then you must add the js script link (.js) into the index.html.

```
Example:

<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/plugin-name/plugin-script.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything is there , but i dont know why i have that error

Comment: Have you add cordova_plugin.js into index.html?

Comment: Well, mediascanner plugin used for native platform (android). And installation for ionic as following: npm i ionic-mediascanner

Comment: i installed already but I don't know how to implement ! any idea please ?

Comment: Unfortunately, its only used for native android platform, so its no available for another platform. But if you have no platform problem, you can try to validate its dependencies.

Comment: i have native android platform but i dont know how to use after installed

Comment: I understand. But if the plugin has deprecated or outdated, you must ask for the update to the author, or you find another one.